# is it possible to control desktop icons from batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

is it possible to move an icon around the desktop with a batch script like when moving it with the cursor?.

i tried searching google about the LVM_SETITEMPOSITION
but i have no idea if it would be possible to use that in any way

Comment: Related: [Where does Windows store icon positions?](http://superuser.com/a/630740/376602)

Comment: You will probably need some helper program\programs.